# Binary Search Tree Recursive insert not displaying anything

Tags: java, recursion, insert, binary-search-tree

I'm doing a small Java work on Binary Search Tree but when I'm implementing the recursive insert of a node into the tree and display it, I don't get anything. I've been on it for a while now, I don't know for sure but I think it's a pass-by-reference problem.

Here's my code:

```
public class BST {

    private BSTNode root; 

    public BST() {
        root = null;
    }

    public BSTNode getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void insertR( BSTNode root, Comparable elem ) {

        if ( root == null ) {
            root = new BSTNode( elem );
        }
        else {
            if ( elem.compareTo( root.element ) < 0 ) {
                insertR( root.left, elem );
            } else {
                insertR( root.right, elem );
            }
        }

    }

    public void printInOrder (BSTNode root) {
        if (root != null) {

            printInOrder(root.left);
            System.out.println(root.element);
            printInOrder(root.right);

        }
    }
}

class BSTNode {

    protected Comparable element;
    protected BSTNode left;
    protected BSTNode right;

    protected BSTNode ( Comparable elem ) {

        element = elem;
        left = null;
        right = null;

    }

}
```

I executed a series of insertR with the root being the node to insert into and the elem is a string but it doesn't print anything out, as if the tree was not filled in at all. I'm sure it's problem with my recursive insert but I'm not sure where, I need to use a recursive insert method that returns nothing which I think is impossible.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Shudn't the  second line will be private BSTNode root??

Comment: also you dint add the constructor for the comparable element

Comment: Yeah it's supposed to be BSTNode root, sorry for not checking that part. The comparable element can be anything, in this case I'm using strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your left, right element of the BSTNodes are null. You need to create them before inserting into it. Otherwise they create an empty hanging BSTNode() and insert it, without connecting to the rest of the tree.

You can change the lines,

```
            if ( elem.compareTo( root.element ) < 0 ) {
                insertR( root.left, elem );
            } else {
                insertR( root.right, elem );
            }
```

to

```
 if ( elem.compareTo( root.element ) < 0 ) {
        if ( root.left == null )
             root.left = new BSTNode( elem );
        else
            insertR( root.left, elem );
    } else {
        if ( root.right == null )
             root.right = new BSTNode( elem );
        else
             insertR( root.right, elem );
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code, it seems that the root is never set anything, I tried printing some dummy string if it ever passes into the else for `if ( root == null )` so I'm still not sure.

Comment: Hey I finally got it, with the help of your snippet and an extra if statement afterwards, I got it to work, thanks! Btw, this is the line I added: `if (root.element != null) this.root = root` after the `root = new BSTNode( elem );`

Answer (score 1):

Though recursive insertion into BST seems trivial, it's very easy to make an argument passing mistake that'd nullify your attempts. To recursively call the insertion function, you must pass the object `BSTNode root` as one of the argument **AND make changes to its content** instead of what it points to.

In the following code, `root = new BSTNode( elem );` only changes the address that the local variable `root` is pointing at, and the change is not visible to `this.root`. Before the assignment, `root` has a value of `null`, which was value-copied from `this.root` when the BST was empty. After the assignment, `root` points at some newly created `BSTNode` with data from `elem`. Intention of the code is to make `this.root` point to the same new `BSTNode`, yet there is no way to achieve that by making the local `root` point to it. When `insertR` returns, `this.root` still points to `null`!!

Same mistakes happen to `insertR(root.left, elem);` and `insertR(root.right, elem);`. Arguments are passed, but since no content changes are made, the function call would just return with no information updated to the BST.

```
public void insert(Comparable elem) {
    insertR(this.root, elem);
}

public void insertR( BSTNode root, Comparable elem ) {

    if ( root == null ) {
        root = new BSTNode( elem );
    }
    else {
        if ( elem.compareTo( root.element ) < 0 ) {
            insertR( root.left, elem );
        } else {
            insertR( root.right, elem );
        }
    }

}
```

To recursively change a BST, changes shall be made towards the variable(s) an object contains instead of what the object variable points at. Thus when `this.root` is `null`, you should handle the first insertion somewhere else instead of inside `insertR`, like the following:

```
public void insert(Comparable elem) {
    if (this.root == null) {
        this.root = new BSTNode(elem);
    } else {
        insertR(this.root, elem);
    }
}
```

The code by Arcturus for additional insertions was correct because the changes made to the contents of `root` immediately spreads to `this.root`, as they are point at the same `BSTNode` object. Of course here `root` is required not to be `null`, which is satisfied because `null` case has been handled in the code above.

```
if ( elem.compareTo( root.element ) < 0 ) {
    if ( root.left == null )
         root.left = new BSTNode( elem );
    else
        insertR( root.left, elem );
} else {
    if ( root.right == null )
         root.right = new BSTNode( elem );
    else
         insertR( root.right, elem );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sets the BST root and allow the class to work properly, change

```
    if ( root == null ) {
        root = new BSTNode( elem );
    }
```

to

```
    if ( root == null ) {
        root = new BSTNode( elem );
        if ( root.element != null ) {
            this.root = root;
        }
    }
```