# How to implement a pure tail-recursive insert for BST?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, tail-recursion

All implementations on `insert` for BST is non-tail recursive.

Is that possible to write a **tail-recursive insert** for BST?

If it is possible, how?

Comment: Use iteration. `</sarcasm>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It **is** possible: for example, by writing the `insert` function in [continuation-passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style).

e.g. in [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/)

```
#lang racket

(struct bst-node (left right value) #:transparent)

(define (insert tree new-value)
  (insert-cps tree new-value (lambda (x) x)))

(define (insert-cps tree new-value cont)
  (cond
    [(empty? tree) (cont (bst-node empty empty new-value))]
    [else (match-let ([(bst-node l r v) tree])
            (cond
              [(= v new-value) (cont (bst-node l r v))]
              [(< new-value v) (insert-cps l new-value (lambda (t) (cont (bst-node t r v))))]
              [else (insert-cps r new-value (lambda (t) (cont (bst-node l t v))))]))]))

(insert (insert (insert empty 10) 15) 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add to the solution, you can also do something as following (I implement it in F#):

```
let Insert element bst=
    //find where the element need to be inserted
    let mutable next = bst.Root
    let rec insert n r =
        match n,r with
        |_ when n < r.Data && r.LeftNode.IsNone -> r
        |_ when n > r.Data && r.RightNode.IsNone -> r
        |_ when n = r.Data -> r
        |_ -> if n < r.Data then 
                  next <- r.LeftNode.Value
              else 
                  next <- r.RightNode.Value
              insert n next
    let n = insert element bst.Root

    //if duplicate is found return false
    if n.Data = element then
        false
    else //otherwise create new node
        let node: BSTNode<'a> ={
            Data = element
            LeftNode = None
            RightNode = None
        }
        //insert into proper postion (left or right accordingly)
        if n.Data > node.Data then
            n.LeftNode <- Some(node)
            true
        else 
            n.RightNode <- Some(node)
            true
```

The recursive method is tail recursive, there is no stack buildup. Basic the recursive method find you the place to be inserted. Then if what to be inserted is not yet inside the tree insert it with a simple comparsion.

Answer (score -1):

See if this code works for you.

```
public class TailInsertion {

    class Node {
        int dat;
        Node left;
        Node right;

        Node(int dat) {
            this.dat = dat;
        }
    }

    public void insert(Node root, Node parent, int dat) {

        if (root == null) {
            if (parent == null) {
                return;
            } else {
                if (parent.dat <= dat) {
                    parent.right = new Node(dat);
                    return;
                } else {
                    parent.left = new Node(dat);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        Node node = null;
        if (root.dat <= dat) {
            node = root.right;
        } else {
            node = root.left;
        }

        insert(node, root, dat);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this `insert` be used when the tree is empty?

Comment: @abeln, this recursive `insert` can't, yet neither other recursive version can. When `root==null` && `parent==null`, one can construct a `Node` by `root = new Node(dat)`, yet this assignment cannot be aware outside the function call, see [this explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736832/binary-search-tree-recursive-insert-not-displaying-anything/17894787#17894787) for elaboration.

Comment: @lcn Just because you can't do it in Java, doesn't mean it's not possible with any language. It's easy enough to do in C++ using pointers / pass-by-reference (and probably other languages too).

Comment: @Dukeling, yep, I forgot to mention the scope was Java.

Answer (score -2):

Isn't this tail recursive?

```
void insert(Tree *t, int val) {
    if (t == NULL || val == t->Value) {
        return;
    }
    Tree *next = NULL;
    if (val < t->Value)
        next = t->Left;
    else
        next = t->Right;
    insert(next, val);
}
```

Comment: The function seems to be missing the actual insert.