# Why does assigning value to null object not work in my code? My code has a simple insert function for a Binary Search Tree:

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
    public class Node {

    Node left;
    Node right;
    int value;

    public Node(int value){

          this.value = value;
          this.left = null;
          this.right = null;
    }

    public void printValue(){

       System.out.println("Node value = "+this.value);
    }  
    }
```

Now in Binary Search Tree class I have an insert function:

```
    public class BinarySearchTree {

    Node root;

public BinarySearchTree(int value){
    Node n = new Node(value);   
this.root = n;
    }

public void insert(int value, Node root){

    Node current = root;      
    Node n = new Node(value);
    while(current != null){

                 if (value > current.value)
                       current = current.right;
                 else if (value < current.value)
                       current = current.left;
          }

          current = n;

    }
```

Here is the driver class:

```
    public class GTDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BinarySearchTree bt = new BinarySearchTree(50);
    bt.insert(45, bt.root);
    bt.insert(65, bt.root);

    bt.root.printValue();
    bt.root.left.printValue();
    bt.root.right.printValue();
}

    }
```

This code gives null pointer exception after printing root. The value is not getting assigned in the 'insert' function when the 'current' value is null.

However, the following modification to insert function resolves the error:

```
    public void insert(int value, Node root){

    Node current = root;      
    Node n = new Node(value);

    while(current != null){

        if (value > current.value)  
            if (current.right != null)
              current = current.right;
            else{
                current.right = n;
                break;
            }
        else if (value < current.value)
            if (current.left != null)
                current = current.left;
            else{
                current.left = n;
                break;
            }
    }           
    }
```

Why does the previous insert function not work?

Answer (score 1):

In

```
   bt.root.left.printValue();
   bt.root.right.printValue();
```

both

```
bt.root.left
bt.root.right
```

are null, So you are getting NullPointerException..

public void insert(int value, Node root){

```
Node current = root;      
Node n = new Node(value);
while(current != null){

             if (value > current.value)
                   current = current.right;   
             else if (value < current.value)
                   current = current.left;    
      }

      current = n;  // n.right=null and n.left=null. So, current.right and current.left=null.

}
```

In the second case,

```
 if (value > current.value)  
            if (current.right != null)
              current = current.right;
            else{
                current.right = n;   //right!=null
                break;
            }
        else if (value < current.value)
            if (current.left != null)
                current = current.left;
            else{
                current.left = n;   // left!=null
```

Answer (score 1):

The analysis is pretty straight forward. In your first insert-version you have root with null refs to subnodes (left and right are null). The insert method does not really do anything, because:

```
    Node current = root;      
    Node n = new Node(value);
    while (current != null) {
          if (value > current.value)
                 current = current.right; // null assignment!
          } else if (value < current.value) {
                 current = current.left; // null assignment!
          }
     }

 // here current is null
```

then you create a new node n and forget to assign it to left and right of root node.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to assign left and right node when you insert.

Instead of use a iterative method I recommend use recursion. It is very very easy.

```
public void insert(int value, Node root){
     if (root == null) {
        root = new Node(value);
     } else {
        if (root.getValue() >= value) {
           if (root.getRight() == null) {
               root.setRight(new Node(value));
           } else {
               root.insert(value, root.getRight());
           }
        } else {
           if (root.getLeft() == null) {
               root.setLeft(new Node(value));
           } else {
               root.insert(value, root.getLeft());
           }
        }
     }
}
```

EDIT: I just edited this to make it right.

Comment: WRONG answer! This code gives Nullpointer Exception as you are passing a null value in root variable.

Comment: The error you made is discussed in the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736832/binary-search-tree-recursive-insert-not-displaying-anything

Comment: Oh, okay, my mistake. I have not tested this on java